# PHP and MySQL Subtract Seconds From Time

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2:00 in a table and I would like to subtract 0:01 from it. I have tried in a recent post before this one, but it is no help.

In PHP and MySQL, how would I subtract 1 second from 2 minutes?

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['time'])) {
    mysql_select_db("aleckaza_pennyauction", $connection);
    $query = "SELECT Current_Time FROM Live_Auctions WHERE ID='1'";
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $newTime = $row['Current_Time'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO Live_Auctions(Current_Time) VALUES('".$newTime."')";
        $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The column is called Current_Time and the value is 2:00.

Comment: And its ***type***? Is it a `VARCHAR` or a `TIME`?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it's text.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it straight on the DB using MySQL **[`SUBTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime)**

```sql
// from the manual
mysql> SELECT SUBTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999','1 1:1:1.000002');
        -> '2007-12-30 22:58:58.999997'
```

Or you can get the time from MySQL and do it on PHP using [**`DateTime::sub()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-sub.php)

```php
 // again from the manual
 <?php 
 $dateA = date_sub('2000-01-20', date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 second')); 
 ?>
```

Comment: The column is called Current_Time and the value is 2:00. How would this be turned into something I can query to that value?

Comment: `SELECT SUBTIME(Current_Time, 0 0:0:1.00000) as curr_time_changed FROM xyz WHERE ykg = zkj`

Comment: Why curr_time_changed? What does that do?

Comment: The notation `as curr_time_changed` gives the column a name when retrieving it from a resultset row. That's all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just confused on this one. I have updated my code to see if that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Check

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html for MySQL functions,

and http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php for PHP.

Comment: But how would I use 2:00 from the database?

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2:00','%m:%s');

Comment: And then add -1 to the end of the query to remove one second?

Comment: Read the documentation: SELECT DATE_SUB('your datetime expression', INTERVAL 1 SECOND);

Answer (score 0):

[PHP: time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
>   Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

This, -1, into [PHP date()](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) should do the trick.

Comment: But how would I use 2:00 from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code in php flavor, with what u provided-

```
<?php
$t1= '0:2:00';
$t2= '0:0:01';
$a1 = explode(":",$t1);
$a2 = explode(":",$t2);
$time1 = (($a1[0]*60*60)+($a1[1]*60)+($a1[2]));
$time2 = (($a2[0]*60*60)+($a2[1]*60)+($a2[2]));
$diff = abs($time1-$time2);
$hours = floor($diff/(60*60));
$mins = floor(($diff-($hours*60*60))/(60));
$secs = floor(($diff-(($hours*60*60)+($mins*60))));
$result = $hours.":".$mins.":".$secs;
echo $result;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It doesn't subtract 1 second to make it 1:59, it is right now saying 18:59.

Comment: How can you make it so it outputs 00:01:59?